# Get ng-model value from inside ng-repeat using ng-change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

Guys I am new to angular and having problems getting value of ng-model from inside ng-repeat.

I have an array of users, and I want to appoint users with different access levels

```
users = [
{id:1, level:0},
{id:2, level:0},
{id:3, level:0}
]
```

This is the HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">
{{user.id}}-
<select name="appoint" ng-change="appoint(user.id)" ng-model="appointLevel">
   <option value=0>Revoke</option>
   <option value=1>Moderator</option>
   <option value=2>Admin</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

The `appoint()` function in angular:

```
$scope.appoint = function(id){
    console.log(id+' '+appointLevel)
  }
```

The function is working fine and I am getting value of `id` but not `appointLevel' of the input element that has triggered that function.

How can I get the value **console.log(id+' '+appointLevel)** efficiently on `ng-change'?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried $scope.appointLevel ?

Comment: Yes it gives `undefined`

Comment: try putting $scope.appointLevel.value in ng-model as well as in console. Do note that dot matters in angular veriable scoping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
<select name="appoint" ng-change="appoint(user.id, appointLevel)" ng-model="appointLevel">
```

and

```
$scope.appoint = function(id, appointLevel) {
    console.log(id + ' ' + appointLevel);
}
```

You can't access appointLevel from the JS function directly, because it's in the scope of the ng-repeat, which is a child scope  of the controller scope (i.e. $scope).

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uvBpauQuNvnO0miYY0UA?p=preview)

Or you could store the appointLevel in the user itself:

```
<select name="appoint" ng-change="appoint(user)" ng-model="user.appointLevel">
```

and

```
$scope.appoint = function(user) {
    console.log(user.id + ' ' + user.appointLevel);
}
```

Comment: Yes I already figured that out, but any other way doing it without passing that argument.

Comment: That's the simplest way of doing. You could also store the appointLevel in the user itself, and pass the user as argument to the function: http://plnkr.co/edit/NvD0H9KPRZNft9aqWoQ1?p=preview

Comment: hi @JBNizet , can you please explain why $scope.appointLevel results in undefined ??

Comment: Because ng-repeat has its own scope. So, when you select an option in the select box, angular sets the value of the ngRepeat's scope.appointLevel. Not the value of the controller's scope.appointLevel.

Comment: Thanks that is almost what I wanted, is to keed code clean thus by passing just user argument.
Can you please make an answer of above link (plnkr.co), so that I can mark that as accepted.